# Widths aren't aligning on a higher screen resolution

Tags: html, css

It seems to work fine on other browsers and resolutions but not on 1920 x 1080. See image link below. The "about us" blue bar is wider than the image.

[Image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bt2Jh.jpg)

[Issue found towards the bottom of the page on the about us image/link](http://www.wtsolutions.co.za)

Some help solving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have [**tried so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is not wide enough. 
This should solve the problem.

```
.frontbutton.hpimg4::before {
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
.frontbutton.hpimg4::before {
width: -webkit-fill-available;
background-image: url(about-us.jpg);
}
```

with this

```
.frontbutton.hpimg4::before {
width: -webkit-fill-available;
background-image: url(about-us.jpg);
background-size: cover;
}
```

In your style.css

Its located in wp-content/themes/vantage-child/ folder

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your fix was also right, nice explanation, thanks!